# How do I get rid of the gaps between the tiles?

Tags: java, netbeans

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.me.images;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameTester {

```
public JPanel createContentPane() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));
    mainPanel.setBorder(null);
    JButton[] label = new JButton[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        label[i] = new JButton();
        label[i].setSize(50, 50);
        label[i].setBorderPainted(false);
        label[i].setBorderPainted(false);
        label[i].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        panel.add(label[i]);
        panel.setBorder(null);
        label[i].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/me/images/O.png")));
        label[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        label[i].setToolTipText("label" + i);
        label[i].setBorder(null);
        label[i].setBorderPainted(false);
        label[i].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));

    }

    panel.add(mainPanel);
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Board");
    JFrameTester Display = new JFrameTester();

    //try here for layout space
    frame.setContentPane(Display.createContentPane());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

}
```

}
/**
 *
 * @author Alexa
 */

Comment: Please give us some idea about what you need and till where you have reached.

Comment: I am trying to build a Board game in Java and create beans to facilitate that. It will take time but I'm working on tutorials etc. every day to improve myself.

Comment: Is the below given solution is right to your requirement? Then why it is not ticked as right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `JButton` to `mainPanel` instead of `panel`.

Some duplicated lines and not necessary settings removed

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    label[i] = new JButton();
    label[i].setBorderPainted(false);
    mainPanel.add(label[i]);
    label[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass()
        .getResource("/org/me/images/O.png")));
    label[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    label[i].setToolTipText("label" + i);
}
```